# Which encoding supports this symbol ƒ?

Tags: symbols

I have this encoding in my file:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %unicode support
```

but I still get the error

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8... not set up for use with ...
```

**How can you make LaTeX understand the symbol ƒ?**

Comment: Are you talking about an italic `f`? If you copied it from some source, try to delete and type again directly on the editor.

Comment: @Sigur I guess, he’s talking about [Ƒ and ƒ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C6%91). — The problem is not the (input) encoding, this can be solved with `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` or the `newunicodechar` package. You will need a font that includes those glyphs. (The Libertine family does this with XeLaTeX.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The glyphs [Ƒ and ƒ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C6%91) can be used with the `T4` font encoding with `\m F` and `\m F`. To use them with the UTF8 input encoding, one can use the [`newunicodechar`](http://ctan.org/pkg/newunicodechar) and its `\newunicodechar` macro

```
\newunicodechar{ƒ}{{\fontencoding{T4}\selectfont\m f}}
\newunicodechar{Ƒ}{{\fontencoding{T4}\selectfont\m F}}
```

Unfortunately, they seem to only exist in Bitmap versions.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T4, OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ƒ}{{\fontencoding{T4}\selectfont\m f}}
\newunicodechar{Ƒ}{{\fontencoding{T4}\selectfont\m F}}
\begin{document}
abcdeƒgh ABCDEƑGH
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I opened a new thread about the conflict that I got with the symbol: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139251/conflict-with-packages-in-printing-out

Answer (score 3):

With `XeLaTeX`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Calibri}  %% Calibri Unicode MS

\begin{document}

ƒ  Ƒ 

\end{document}
```

[image]