# Conflict with packages in printing out ƒ in \begin{equation} mode

Tags: symbols, tex-core

The initial thread solved the main [problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139048/which-encoding-supports-this-symbol), but there is now some conflict with packages that I do not understand.

My tex code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, textcomp}
\usepackage[T4, OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Arial Unicode MS}
\newunicodechar{ƒ}{{\fontencoding{T4}\selectfont\m f}}
\newunicodechar{Ƒ}{{\fontencoding{T4}\selectfont\m F}}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
Qƒ(x,\eta)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I see the symbol ƒ as

[image]

**What is causing the conflict?**

Comment: I am using XeLaTeX.

Comment: I removed the line **utf8 inputenc**. It solved one of my other problem, but not the problem here. Same printing keeps coming.

Comment: @Masi Please make a complete example that shows the problem, possibly with a standard class; if you're not able to reproduce the issue with the `article` class, please add a reference to a page where `bcmart` is available. Also knowing what fonts you're using along with `unicode-math` would be useful.

Comment: I changed the class into article. The same code applies there with same errors. I have not specified any other font than listed above in the code. **Is it needed?**

Comment: @Masi This is not a complete example; we need to see what produces the wrong output, so some usage in the `document` environment.

Comment: @egrep I added more thorough example of my layout.

Comment: @Masi You are using ƒ wrongly. A function *f* simply uses the letter `f`, math-mode is typeset in italic anyway. The letter [ƒ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C6%91) is separate letter.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I think italic *f* is different thing as the italic symbol: *ƒ*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your original question the solution uses the cmr-family. When using `unicode-math` the family (and the fallback-family) is changed to lmr and so your command fails. You will have to choose the family explicitly. This here works for me on miktex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, textcomp}
\usepackage[T4, OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\newunicodechar{ƒ}{{\fontencoding{T4}\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\m f}}
\newunicodechar{Ƒ}{{\fontencoding{T4}\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\m F}}

\begin{document}
ƒ Ƒ
\end{document}
```

Btw: The font used to create the symbols is a bitmap font. So the symbols will not look good when scaled. It would be much better if you looked for some open type font containing the symbols and would used it like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, textcomp}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Arial Unicode MS}
\begin{document}
ƒ Ƒ abc
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code works that way in my system. I tried in a clean environment. My codes must have some conflict problem. I have to clean my code to understand it.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the environment: \begin{equation} ƒ \end{equation}. This \text{ƒ} does not even help.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the characters in math mode, but `\m` can't.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T4]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{ƒ}{\text{\fontencoding{T4}\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\m f}}
\newunicodechar{Ƒ}{\text{\fontencoding{T4}\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\m F}}

\begin{document}
$\overline{ƒ(t)}+Ƒ$
\end{document}
```

However, I would discourage you from using `ƒ` as a math symbol, because it's barely distinguishable from a normal italic “f”.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the problem with examples, extension to Ulrike's answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, textcomp}
\usepackage[T4, OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\newunicodechar{ƒ}{{\fontencoding{T4}\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\m f}}
\newunicodechar{Ƒ}{{\fontencoding{T4}\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\m F}}

\begin{document}

This is text-mode
ƒ

In the equation mode
\begin{equation}
\text{ƒ}
\end{equation}

and without text-mode

\begin{equation}
ƒ
\end{equation}

and for comparison just f

\begin{equation}
f
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Output

[image]