# Automatically size the brackets by \left and \right

Tags: math-mode, brackets

My tex code

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, textcomp}
\usepackage[T4, OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newunicodechar{ƒ}{{\fontencoding{T4}\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\m f}}
\newunicodechar{Ƒ}{{\fontencoding{T4}\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont\m F}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{align} 
x\left(a + \left(b-a\right) &\frac{k-1}{N}\right)\\
&= \lambda x y 
\end{align}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

and I get the output

[image]

**How can you automatically size the brackets with *\left* and *\right*?**

Comment: You must not nest the environments `equation` and `align`. Choose one or the other. In this case `align` is your friend due to the alignment character (`&`) in your equation.

Comment: Ok, this is a simplification. This equation continues to two lines.

Comment: Also if you are using xetex (or luatex) which can use fonts with thousands of characters why use 7bit `OT1` encoding and fonts with at most 128 characters?, that is rather a bizarre choice.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am using XeLaTeX.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Your equation does not work in my XeLaTeX.

Comment: @Masi yes that is clear, so why `OT1` ?

Comment: -1: In my opinion, this question doesn't show much research effort, and clarification via comments make it seem even worse.

Comment: Expanding fences to cover the material inside is explained on every LaTeX primer.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I think it is a single equation. If you use `align` you get two aligned equations...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Context: [Which encoding supports this symbol ƒ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139048) and [Conflict with packages in printing out ƒ in \begin{equation} mode](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139251)

Comment: @karlkoeller  Isee what you mean now.  I had left out second line... focused on the `&` char.  Deleting earlier comments

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes It is not a good practice anyway to use `align` for a single equation, IMHO.

Comment: Your Minimal Working Example (MWE) should be as minimal as possible. Some part of your MWE can be removed without loss of your intent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that this is the result you wanted to achieve:

[image]

this is a MWE to obtain it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
x\biggl(a + (b-a)&\frac{k-1}{N}\biggr)\\
& \lambda x y
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

---

And these are the errors in your MWE:

1. You cannot put an `align` environment inside an `equation`. If you want a single equation just use `equation` (with no alignment characters `&` inside). If you want multiple aligned equations use `align`. But, as in your case, if you want to align stuff inside a single equation, use a `split` environment inside an `equation`.
2. If you want to use `\left` and `\right` to "automatically size the brackets" they have to be in the same equation and there should be no `&` between them. You can use `\left.` and `\right.` to match the missing pairs, but in your case this doesn't work well because `\left` and `\right` are applied to things with different size. In this case (and probably always) is much better to use fixed size commands like `\biggl` and `\biggr`.

Answer (score 3):

It is true that `\left` and `\right` must be in the same equation, as @karlkoeller said, and therefore, one can only use commands such as `\bigg` to resize the brackets manually. However, the code, whose output is perfect, provided by @karlkoeller doesn't match the OP's damand --- automatic. After a few hours' test, I got this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
x\left(a + (b-a)\phantom{\rlap{$\displaystyle\frac{k-1}{N}$}}\right.&\left.\phantom{\rlap{$a + (b-a)$}}\frac{k-1}{N}\right)\\
& \left.\lambda x y\right.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

And its output:

[image]

`\phantom` makes it invisible, and `\rlap` makes its argument occupy nothing. And this is what the OP was looking for.

My answer, in my opinion, is right, but not great. Although nobody would use it in his/her formal thesis or paper, it's a nice attempt.